# How do I encode categorical values in a Pandas DataFrame using a dictionary scheme given in an Excel file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame with a key attribute and other categorical attributes. How can I encode the categorical attributes using the 'dictionary' in this excel file?

[This is the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Amd3.png)

[and this is the excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUpLV.png)

I want to encode every categorical variable, say, for example, ACGB03A from the DataFrame by looking it up in the 'VARIABLE' column of the excel file, and getting the corresponding integer value from the 'Value Scheme Detail' column.

'VARIABLE' is the key, and 'Value Scheme Detail' gives the encoding details. I need to encode it from the string in the DataFrame to the corresponding integer specified in the 'Value Scheme Detail' column for the particular 'VARIABLE'.

I have around 300 columns in the dataset, so I'd like a way to encode automatically without hardcoding the strings and integers in.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
import pandas as pd

def categorizer(val):
  if val == '0 to 10%':
    return 1
  elif val == '11 to 25%':
    return 2
  elif val == '26 to 50%':
    return 3
  else:
    return 4

df = pd.DataFrame({'11 to 25%'}, columns = ['ACBG03A'])
excel = pd.DataFrame({'variable': ['ACBG03A'], 'VSD': [11]})
temp = excel[excel['variable'].isin(df.columns)]
temp['enc'] = temp['VSD'].apply(categorizer)
```

Result:

[image]

I created the excel file, but you need just to read that using `read_excel`.

Based on the comments:

```
def autodic(string):
  temp = string.replace(';', '",').replace(':', ':"')
  temp = '{'+temp+'"'+'}'
  return eval(temp)
```

Comment: I'd like a way to encode every such categorical value in the DataFrame this way :)

Comment: It works. I used one column for demonstration.

Comment: Hmm, I need to encode the string  "0 to 10%" to 1, "11 to 25%" to 2, "26 to 50%" to 3, and "More than 50%" to 4.

And so forth for all the other columns.

Comment: Easy, I will edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to read in the 'dictionary' under the VSD column and encode the variable automatically, without having to hardcode the values? My dataset contains around 300 columns I have to do this to :)

Comment: See the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler and faster solution to your problem can be to just create a dictionary from your column using split and then map it to all the required columns.
Here if your data frame is df --

```
import pandas as pd

excel_read = pd.DataFrame(excel_file.xlsx)
# Removing rows with Value Scheme Detailed as NaN for creating dictionary
excel = excel_read[excel_read['Value Scheme Detailed'].notna()]

l = []
for s in excel['Value Scheme Detailed']:
    l.append({item.split(":")[1]:int(item.split(":")[0]) for item in s.split(";")}) #remove int if final values needed as text
d = dict(zip(excel['Variable'], l))

columns_to_map = [] # add all columns where you want to map from excel
for col in columns_to_map:
    df[col] = df[col].map(d[col])
```

Comment: I'm getting AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Updated the code, there are NaN in Value Scheme Detailed and since when you map NaN to your final df it will just replace the whole column to NaN, we can just filter rows out for the purpose of creating this dictionary where it has NaN